# Why does my Alpha-Beta pruning expand more nodes than necessary?

Tags: python, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning, pacman

I am currently implementing an alpha-beta pruning algorithm for a minimax function. This exercise corresponds to the multiagent section of the PacMan Project at Berkeley University.

My implementation:

```
class AlphaBetaAgent(MultiAgentSearchAgent):
    """
    Your minimax agent with alpha-beta pruning (question 3)
    """

    def getAction(self, gameState):
        """
        Returns the minimax action using self.depth and self.evaluationFunction
        """
        "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
        def maxValue(state, depth: int, alpha: int, beta: int):
            depth += 1
            if state.isWin() or state.isLose() or depth == self.depth:
                return self.evaluationFunction(state)
            else:
                value: int = -sys.maxsize - 1
                legalActions: list = state.getLegalActions(0)
                for action in legalActions:
                    value = max(value, minValue(
                        state.generateSuccessor(0, action), 1, depth, alpha, beta))
                    if beta <= value:
                        return value
                    alpha = max(alpha,value)
            return value

        def minValue(state, ghostIndex: int, depth: int, alpha: int, beta: int):
            if state.isWin() or state.isLose():
                return self.evaluationFunction(state)
            else:
                value: int = sys.maxsize * 2 + 1
                legalActions: list = state.getLegalActions(ghostIndex)
                if ghostIndex == state.getNumAgents() - 1:
                    for action in legalActions:
                        value = min(value, maxValue(
                            state.generateSuccessor(ghostIndex, action), depth, alpha, beta))
                else:
                    for action in legalActions:
                        value = min(value, minValue(state.generateSuccessor(
                            ghostIndex, action), ghostIndex + 1, depth, alpha, beta))
                        if alpha >= value:
                            return value
                        beta = min (beta, value)
                return value

        pacManMoves: list = gameState.getLegalActions(0)
        value: int = -sys.maxsize - 1
        alpha: int = -sys.maxsize - 1
        beta: int = sys.maxsize*2+1
        move: str = Directions.STOP
        for currentMove in pacManMoves:
            currentValue = minValue(
                gameState.generateSuccessor(0, currentMove), 1, 0, alpha, beta)
            if (currentValue > value):
                value = currentValue
                move = currentMove
        return move
```

Output:

```
Question q3
===========

*** PASS: test_cases\q3\0-eval-function-lose-states-1.test
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\0-eval-function-lose-states-2.test
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\0-eval-function-win-states-1.test
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\0-eval-function-win-states-2.test
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\0-lecture-6-tree.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=2
***         Student generated nodes: A B C D E F G H I max min1 min2 min3
***         Correct generated nodes: A B C D E F G H max min1 min2 min3
***     Tree:
***                max
***           /-/   |   \--\
***          /      |       \
***         /       |        \
***      min1      min2      min3
***       /|\      /|\       /|\
***      / | \    / | \     / | \
***     A  B  C  D  E  F   G  H  I
***     3 12  8  5  4  6  14  1  11
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\0-small-tree.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=3
***         Student generated nodes: A B C D deeper minLeft minRight root
***         Correct generated nodes: A B C minLeft minRight root
***     Tree:
***             root
***            /    \
***      minLeft  minRight
***       / \       /    \
***      A   B     C   deeper
***      4   3     2     |
***                      D
***                    1000
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\1-1-minmax.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=3
***         Student generated nodes: a b1 b2 c1 c2 cx d1 d2 d3 d4 dx
***         Correct generated nodes: a b1 b2 c1 c2 cx d1 d2 d3 dx
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***           /    \                 |
***        c1        c2             cx
***       /  \      /  \             |
***      d1   d2  d3   d4           dx
***     -3    -9  10    6         -3.01
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - max
***
***     Note that the minimax value of b1 is -3.
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\1-2-minmax.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=3
***         Student generated nodes: a b1 b2 c1 c2 cx d1 d2 d3 d4 dx
***         Correct generated nodes: a b1 b2 c1 c2 cx d1 d2 d3 dx
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***           /    \                 |
***        c1        c2             cx
***       /  \      /  \             |
***      d1   d2  d3   d4           dx
***     -3    -9  10    6         -2.99
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - max
***
***     Note that the minimax value of b1 is -3.
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\1-3-minmax.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=3
***         Student generated nodes: a b1 b2 c3 c4 cx d5 d6 d7 d8 dx
***         Correct generated nodes: a b1 b2 c3 cx d5 d6 dx
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***              |                /    \
***             cx             c3        c4
***              |            /   \     /   \
***             dx           d5   d6   d7   d8
***            4.01          4    -7   0    5
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - max
***
***     Note that the minimax value of b2 is 4.
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\1-4-minmax.test
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\1-5-minmax.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=4
***         Student generated nodes: A B C D E F G H Z a b1 b2 c1 c2 cx d1 d2 d3 d4 dx
***         Correct generated nodes: A B C D E F G Z a b1 b2 c1 c2 cx d1 d2 d3 d4 dx
***     Tree:
***                  /-----a------\
***                 /              \
***                /                \
***              b1                  b2
***            /    \                |
***         c1        c2             cx
***        /  \      /  \            |
***       d1   d2  d3   d4           dx
***      / \  / \  / \  / \          |
***      A B  C D  E F  G H          Z
***     -3 13 5 9 10 3 -6 8        3.01
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - max
***     d - min
***
***     Note the minimax value of b1 is 3.
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\1-6-minmax.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=4
***         Student generated nodes: A B C D E F G H Z a b1 b2 c1 c2 cx d1 d2 d3 d4 dx
***         Correct generated nodes: A B C D E F G Z a b1 b2 c1 c2 cx d1 d2 d3 d4 dx
***     Tree:
***                  /-----a------\
***                 /              \
***                /                \
***              b1                  b2
***            /    \                |
***         c1        c2             cx
***        /  \      /  \            |
***       d1   d2  d3   d4           dx
***      / \  / \  / \  / \          |
***      A B  C D  E F  G H          Z
***     -3 13 5 9 10 3 -6 8        2.99
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - max
***     d - min
***
***     Note the minimax value of b1 is 3.
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\1-7-minmax.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=4
***         Student generated nodes: I J K L M O P Z a b1 b2 c3 c4 cx d5 d6 d7 d8 dx
***         Correct generated nodes: I J K M O P Z a b1 b2 c3 c4 cx d5 d6 d7 d8 dx
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***             |                 /    \
***             cx             c3        c4
***             |             /   \     /   \
***             dx           d5   d6   d7   d8
***             |           / \  / \  / \  / \
***             Z           I J  K L  M N  O P
***          -1.99        -1 -9  4 7  2 5 -3 -2
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - min
***     d - max
***
***     Note that the minimax value of b2 is -2
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\1-8-minmax.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=4
***         Student generated nodes: I J K L M O P Z a b1 b2 c3 c4 cx d5 d6 d7 d8 dx
***         Correct generated nodes: I J K M O P Z a b1 b2 c3 c4 cx d5 d6 d7 d8 dx
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***             |                 /    \
***             cx             c3        c4
***             |             /   \     /   \
***             dx           d5   d6   d7   d8
***             |           / \  / \  / \  / \
***             Z           I J  K L  M N  O P
***          -2.01        -1 -9  4 7  2 5 -3 -2
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - min
***     d - max
***
***     Note that the minimax value of b2 is -2.01
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\2-1a-vary-depth.test
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\2-1b-vary-depth.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=2
***         Student generated nodes: a b1 b2 c1 c2 cx d1 d2 d3 d4 dx
***         Correct generated nodes: a b1 b2 c1 c2 cx d1 d2 d3 dx
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***           /    \                 |
***     -4 c1        c2 9           cx -4.01
***       /  \      /  \             |
***      d1   d2  d3   d4           dx
***     -3    -9  10    6         -4.01
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - max
***
***     Note that the minimax value of b1 is -3, but the depth=1 limited value is -4.
***     The values next to c1, c2, and cx are the values of the evaluation function, not
***     necessarily the correct minimax backup.
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\2-2a-vary-depth.test
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\2-2b-vary-depth.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=2
***         Student generated nodes: a b1 b2 c1 c2 cx d1 d2 d3 d4 dx
***         Correct generated nodes: a b1 b2 c1 c2 cx d1 d2 d3 dx
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***           /    \                 |
***     -4 c1        c2 9           cx -3.99
***       /  \      /  \             |
***      d1   d2  d3   d4           dx
***     -3    -9  10    6         -3.99
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - max
***
***     Note that the minimax value of b1 is -3, but the depth=1 limited value is -4.
***     The values next to c1, c2, and cx are the values of the evaluation function, not
***     necessarily the correct minimax backup.
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\2-3a-vary-depth.test
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\2-3b-vary-depth.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=2
***         Student generated nodes: a b1 b2 c3 c4 cx d5 d6 d7 d8 dx
***         Correct generated nodes: a b1 b2 c3 cx d5 d6 dx
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***              |                /    \
***      5.01   cx          8  c3        c4   5
***              |            /   \     /   \
***             dx           d5   d6   d7   d8
***            5.01          4    -7   0    5
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - max
***
***     Note that the minimax value of b1 is 4, but the depth=1 limited value is 5.
***     The values next to c3, c4, and cx are the values of the evaluation function, not
***     necessarily the correct minimax backup.
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\2-4a-vary-depth.test
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\2-4b-vary-depth.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=2
***         Student generated nodes: a b1 b2 c3 c4 cx d5 d6 d7 d8 dx
***         Correct generated nodes: a b1 b2 c3 cx d5 d6 dx
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***              |                /    \
***      4.99   cx          8  c3        c4   5
***              |            /   \     /   \
***             dx           d5   d6   d7   d8
***            4.99          4    -7   0    5
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - max
***
***     Note that the minimax value of b1 is 4, but the depth=1 limited value is 5.
***     The values next to c3, c4, and cx are the values of the evaluation function, not
***     necessarily the correct minimax backup.
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\2-one-ghost-3level.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=3
***         Student generated nodes: a b1 b2 c1 c2 c3 c4 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8
***         Correct generated nodes: a b1 b2 c1 c2 c3 d1 d2 d3 d5 d6
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***           /    \              /     \
***        c1        c2        c3        c4
***       /  \      /  \      /   \     /   \
***      d1   d2  d3   d4    d5   d6   d7   d8
***      3    9   10   6     4    7    0    5
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - max
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\3-one-ghost-4level.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=4
***         Student generated nodes: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P a b1 b2 c1 c2 c3 c4 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8
***         Correct generated nodes: A B C D E F I K a b1 b2 c1 c2 c3 d1 d2 d3 d5 d6
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***           /    \              /     \
***        c1        c2        c3        c4
***       /  \      /  \      /   \     /   \
***      d1   d2  d3   d4    d5   d6   d7   d8
***     / \  / \  / \  / \   / \  / \  / \  / \
***     A B  C D  E F  G H   I J  K L  M N  O P
***     3 13 5 9 10 11 6 8   1 0  4 7 12 15 2 14
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - max
***     d - min
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\4-two-ghosts-3level.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=3
***         Student generated nodes: a b1 b2 c1 c2 c3 c4 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8
***         Correct generated nodes: a b1 b2 c1 c2 c3 c4 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***           /    \              /     \
***        c1        c2        c3        c4
***       /  \      /  \      /   \     /   \
***      d1   d2  d3   d4    d5   d6   d7   d8
***      3    9   10   6     4    7    0    5
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - min
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\5-two-ghosts-4level.test
***     Incorrect generated nodes for depth=4
***         Student generated nodes: A B C D E G H I J K L M O a b1 b2 c1 c2 c3 c4 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8
***         Correct generated nodes: A B C D E G H I J a b1 b2 c1 c2 c3 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5
***     Tree:
***                 /-----a------\
***                /              \
***               /                \
***             b1                  b2
***           /    \              /     \
***        c1        c2        c3        c4
***       /  \      /  \      /   \     /   \
***      d1   d2  d3   d4    d5   d6   d7   d8
***     / \  / \  / \  / \   / \  / \  / \  / \
***     A B  C D  E F  G H   I J  K L  M N  O P
***     3 13 5 9 10 11 6 8   1 0  4 7 12 15 2 14
***
***     a - max
***     b - min
***     c - min
***     d - max
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\6-tied-root.test
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\7-1a-check-depth-one-ghost.test
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\7-1b-check-depth-one-ghost.test
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\7-1c-check-depth-one-ghost.test
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\7-2a-check-depth-two-ghosts.test
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\7-2b-check-depth-two-ghosts.test
*** PASS: test_cases\q3\7-2c-check-depth-two-ghosts.test
*** Running AlphaBetaAgent on smallClassic 1 time(s).
Pacman died! Score: 84
Average Score: 84.0
Scores:        84.0
Win Rate:      0/1 (0.00)
Record:        Loss
*** Finished running AlphaBetaAgent on smallClassic after 15 seconds.
*** Won 0 out of 1 games. Average score: 84.000000 ***
*** FAIL: test_cases\q3\8-pacman-game.test
***     Bug: Wrong number of states expanded.
*** Tests failed.
```

There are a lot of functions inherent to the exercise that are already given and that I have not modified. The only function that has been modified for the purpose of the exercise is the one mentioned above.

Source code:
https://github.com/MaAlonsoA/AI-Class/tree/feature/AlphaBetaAgent

Running the autograder with `python autograder.py -q q3`

Running on python 3.9.4

Comment: What part of your code *should* have prevented generation of these nodes, and why *didn't* it do so?  That is, at what point does your code behave unexpectedly?

Comment: The minValue function compares the calculated value with a previously minimum calculated (alpha). If the value obtained is less than or equal to the alpha value, the algorithm is supposed to stop expanding the branch. The same in the maxValue function with the beta value (in this case greater than or equal to beta).
You can find a better explanation (with pseudocode) in the following link. Question 3
http://ai.berkeley.edu/multiagent.html

Comment: *at what point does your code behave unexpectedly?*

Comment: I assume that at the point where the algorithm continues to expand the tree even having found a lower (in the case minValue) or higher (maxValue) value. At this point the program should break the search and return that value.
In the example of the first failed test, the algorithm expands node 'I' even if 'H' is less than alpha (which in this case corresponds to 3, the value of node 'A'). At this point it is assumed that `if alpha >= value` should terminate the path.

Comment: Don't assume: check it!

Comment: Thank you for your time sir, I have found the bugs.

Comment: You did all the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

**There were two bugs in my previous implementation:**

1. Previously in the `minValue` function calculated the value for all *'legal actions'* if there was only one ghost left. This is incorrect, you only have to calculate it once.

   ```
           legalActions: list = state.getLegalActions(ghostIndex)
           if ghostIndex == state.getNumAgents() - 1:
               for action in legalActions:
                   value = min(value, maxValue(
                       state.generateSuccessor(ghostIndex, action), depth, alpha, beta))
           else:
   ```

fixed:

```
        legalActions: list = state.getLegalActions(ghostIndex)
        for action in legalActions:
            if ghostIndex == state.getNumAgents() - 1:
                value = min(value, maxValue(
                        state.generateSuccessor(ghostIndex, action), depth, alpha, beta))
                if alpha > value:
                    return value
                beta = min (beta, value)
            else:
```

2. The `currentValue` needs to be checked to see if it is greater than `beta`.

   ```
       for currentMove in pacManMoves:
       currentValue = minValue(
           gameState.generateSuccessor(0, currentMove), 1, 0, alpha, beta)
       if (currentValue > value):
           value = currentValue
           move = currentMove
   return move
   ```

fixed:

```
        for currentMove in pacManMoves:
        currentValue = minValue(
            gameState.generateSuccessor(0, currentMove), 1, 0, alpha, beta)
        if currentValue > value:
            value = currentValue
            move = currentMove
        if currentValue > beta:
            return move
        alpha = max(alpha, value)
    return move
```